# Postgres: get average for all values of a column for each distinct from another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like:

```
sku | qty
----|----
sku1|  1
sku1|  3
sku1|  1
sku1|  3
sku2|  1
```

And I'm trying to write a query that will return the average of `qty` for each distinct `sku`.
So for the data above, the output from the query would look like:

```
sku | qty
----|----
sku1| 2
sku2| 1
```

So, the averages for `sku1` came from `1 3 1 3` and the average of `sku2` is just `1`

I know it's going to involve some kind of subquery, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
SELECT sku, AVG(qty)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT sku FROM table)
```

How do I query for the average qty for each sku?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's precisely what `group by` is for:

```
SELECT sku, AVG(qty)
FROM the_table
GROUP BY sku;
```

The manual has some examples: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP